# Invalid bell character inside XML tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm using `Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document` to parse an XML file filled by shopping itens.

Some of these items have a paragraph with a bell character in it, without a CDATA block section:

```
<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind. ^G Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>
```

* `^G`  is how this character appear in VIM.

The parsing of that element fails and then I get the following error:

```
XML document contains errors, check this: PCDATA invalid Char value 7.
```

Is there a way to read the element shown above ignoring that invalid character in Nokogiri?

Comment: Without the XML data in context and an example of your code it's really difficult to say what the problem is.  See "[ask]". We're not going to write SAX code so we need you to show us what you've tried. As is, it's valid XML markup, so the error probably occurs elsewhere in the XML, and is throwing off the parser.

Comment: The error message refers to “Char value 7”. Character 7 is a control character (the [Bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) in ASCII), which isn’t valid in XML (1.0 at least). When I create a sample doc containing that character and parse it I get the same error message. Your problem is this character, not the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an invalid character; `:` is perfectly valid in a text node. The problem has to lie elsewhere, probably due to invalid XML in the document that is confusing libXML as it parses the document.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind. Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>')
doc.to_xml # => "<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind. Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>"
doc.errors # => []

doc.at('description').text # => "Amazing product that will blow your mind. Caution: may cause skin irritation and death."
```

To see if your document is valid, use the `errors` method to have Nokogiri return an array of errors. In the above code it returns an empty array, meaning there's nothing wrong with what was parsed.

---

> ...I discovered which character really is causing the problem...

```
<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind. ^G Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>
```

You can use `tr` or `delete` to remove unwanted characters prior to parsing. Rather than use `^G` in your search string, use `\a` as it's the same value, just easier to deal with:

```
>> "^G".ord#=> 7
>> "\a".ord #=> 7
```

So, you can do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = "<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind. \a Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml.delete("\a"))
doc.to_xml # => "<description>Amazing product that will blow your mind.  Caution: may cause skin irritation and death.</description>"
```

Comment: after re-investigating the situation I discovered which character really is causing the problem, and edited the question

Comment: Occasionally we'll see corrupted markup, either XML or HTML. In HTML it's not as big a deal as it's a very lax standard. XML is much more picky. When we run into problems like this generally it's best to do a pre-flight check and fix the problems we know exist prior to parsing. I'll add an example of what I'd do.

Comment: I'm not sure how I will do this with the SAX Parser, but you already helped me a lot.

Comment: You might have to use `sed` at the command-line to pre-process the file.